# SetDIBitsToDevice fails when using large page

Tags: winapi

I have just discovered that `SetDIBitsToDevice` function fails (returns 0) when I'm trying to display an image which data was allocated via large page using this call:

```
VirtualAlloc(NULL, imageSize, MEM_RESERVE | MEM_COMMIT | MEM_LARGE_PAGES, PAGE_READWRITE)
```

Just after the failure, `GetLastError` returns 0, which means "no error". Note that removing MEM_LARGE_PAGES flag makes the code work correctly.

Is it a bug or a correct behavior? Documentation doesn't say anything about it.

Comment: GDI functions, like this one, do not set the last error state.  Yup, that does make it awfully difficult to figure out exactly what went wrong.  One simple explanation is that VirtualAlloc failed, you can't pass imageSize to allocate MEM_LARGE_PAGES.  It is up to you to bump up the request to an exact multiple of the large page size.  Do beware that large pages are not backed by the paging file, so having it fail on a lack of available RAM will be another common failure mode.  Two reasons to not do this.

Comment: I know VirtualAlloc successfully allocated large page, because I get valid pointer and use the memory in other places without any problem. It's only SetDIBitsToDevice that does not work, that's why I'm asking. I know large page allocation may fail so I have fallback to regular page size.

Comment: I think this is graphic card specific? I seem to remember issues when Heap/LocalAlloc is used as well.